# Applitools: How to implement it?

Tags: java, im4java

I would like to implement visual UI comparison but I don't have the idea on how to implement it. Anyone please give some idea on how to implement visual UI comparison. I know that need to compare the actual and expected screenshot but I don't know when to execute it (Whether it is different test cases or integrate it together to functional testing).

PS: I got an idea - Is it execute all functional testing first then execute visual UI testing?

Please provide some ideas. A billion thanks for your help.

Comment: It uses for Selenium IDE only, I using selenium webdriver/grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Applitools with selenium. It is a nice tool with AI algorithms to compare images. Hence will have less or no false positive scenarios.
It provides nice documentation as well-
Firstly you need to have an account created which will give you a key. Also download the utility. Please refer the below link (this is java integration, similarly you can find other technology integrations as well)-

https://applitools.com/tutorials/selenium-java.html#quick-start-%F0%9F%9A%80